# C++ template: multidimensional array as input

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement an API layer for a C++ project, here's a small example of what I want to achieve:

```
double data[8] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

template<typename T>
void cpy(T *buf){
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
        buf[i] = (T)data[i];
}

int main() {
    int a[8];
    cpy(a);

    float b[8];
    cpy(b);

    double c[2][4]; 
    cpy(c); //error: functional cast to array type 'double [4]'

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is to allow the user to use the function `cpy()` for different types of array without having to do `cpy<double>(c)` or `cpy((double *)c)` but in this example, calling `cpy()` with a 2D array leads to compilation error:

```
error: expected initializer before 'cpy'
 In instantiation of 'void cpy(T*) [with T = double [4]]':
  required from here
error: functional cast to array type 'double [4]'
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: You could use `std::array` or `std::vector`, combined with `std::transform` for the casts, which are the ideomatic C++ mechanisms for storing contiguous arrays of data in stack (`std::array`) or heap (`std::vector`) memory, which already implement the necessary copy functionality and require no boilerplate code on your part.

Comment: `cpy(&c[0][0]);` ? `cpy(c);` would be `cpy<double(*)[4]>(c);`.

Comment: @Xirema, yes you are right. Using std::array and std::vector makes a lot more sense. But is it possible to do that with native C array?

Comment: @Jarod42, the requirement is to implement the API which is **exactly** like `cpy(c)` without having to specify any data type (or knowing the array dimension/size).

Comment: @hhy Is this for a homework assignment? If it's not, then you should try to get the API changed, since this kind of design would be very poor for a professional project. If it's for homework, then you don't really have a choice.

Comment: Notice that you have out of bound access as you loop with 10, whereas size is 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change `main()` (except for typo with missing `;`).
You can add overload:

```
template<typename T>
void cpy(T *buf){
    for (int i = 0; i != 8; ++i) {
        buf[i] = data[i];
    }
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void cpy(T (*buf)[N]){
    cpy(&buf[0][0]);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/HUJd85)

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for!